# Conditionally add @submit.prevent to a form in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-props, vue-events

I'm trying to conditionally prevent HTML form submission using `@submit.prevent`.  I have a generic form model that looks like this (minimized a bit):

```html
<v-form v-model="valid">
   <div>
      <div v-for="(field, i) in fieldConfig" :key="`model-form-`+i">
         <fe-label v-if="field.label">{{field.label}}</fe-label>
         <component 
            :is="field.component" 
            v-bind="field.attrs" 
            v-model="item[field.field]"
          />
       </div>
   </div>
</v-form>
```

Called from a parent:

```html
<model-form
   idProperty="id"
   @done="finishRename"
   model="myModel"
   :fieldConfig="fieldConfig"
   :htmlSubmit="false"
/>
```

I've seen some similar things in my searching but nothing quite right, and I'm pretty raw when it comes to Vue.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Andy pointed out, `@submit.prevent` should not be used for conditional form submission because the [`.prevent` modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers) automatically calls [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

To conditionally call it, you'd have to remove the `.prevent` modifier, and evaluate the `htmlSubmit` flag beforehand within the event handler:

```html
<v-form @submit="onSubmit" action="https://example.com">
```

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    onSubmit(e) {
      if (!this.htmlSubmit) {
        e.preventDefault() // don't perform submit action (i.e., `<form>.action`)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Edit Conditional submit with v-form]

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `submit.prevent` in this scenario. Just use `submit`, and in your function, conditionally prevent.

```
onSubmit(e) {
   if(condition) e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, can you explain a bit more where exactly I'm using submit, and where you'd place this function?  I'm still wrapping my head around Vue.